# Lifecycle callbacks for system activity (PickActivity / Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am working on an Android app that needs to perform a clean-up task (disconnect BLE devices) when the whole application goes to background. I implemented the standard ActivityLifecycleCallbacks and do my book-keeping in the Application class. All is working good as long as I use my *AppCompatActivity* instances within my package.

```
class MainApplication : Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
}

/// Activity counter

var startedActivities = AtomicInteger(0)

private fun activityStarted() {
    if (startedActivities.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        Log.d("PICKERTEST", ">>> APPLICATION STARTED")
    }
}

private fun activityStopped() {
    if (startedActivities.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        Log.d("PICKERTEST", ">>> APPLICATION STOPPED")
    }
}

/// Activity lifecycle callbacks

override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
    activityStarted()
}

override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
    activityStopped()
}

...
```

**MY PROBLEM**: The trouble starts when I have to pick files (for example a Firmware Update) using the system activities. In this case, I don't get callbacks for the picker activity and my app believes it gets paused, as soon as the picker appears. This disconnects the BLE device and, once I get back from the file picker, I cannot upload the firmware file to the device.

The code to open the file picker is pretty standard:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    pickButton.setOnClickListener { pickFile() }
}

private fun pickFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
        this.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        this.type = "*/*"
    }

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
}

...
```

This opens up a system activity with a standard OS picker. According to *adb shell dumpsys activity*:

```
ActivityRecord{e05754 u0 com.android.documentsui/.picker.PickActivity t162}]
```

This activity comes from the *android.documentsui*:

> PickActivity >
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DocumentsUI/+/android-cts-8.0_r16/src/com/android/documentsui/picker/PickActivity.java

> BaseActivity >
> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DocumentsUI/+/android-cts-8.0_r16/src/com/android/documentsui/BaseActivity.java

This package is not androidx-based and uses the standard *android.app.Activity*. To be fair, I am not sure if that is the issue, or if lifecycle callbacks just don't get called when I run an activity from a different package.

I can of course add a custom callback to MainApplication, to notify that we are running an external Activity

```
class MainApplication : Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    
...

    /// Custom callback

    fun onStartActivityForResult() {
        Log.d("PICKERTEST", "onStartActivityForResult")
        activityStarted()
    }

    fun onActivityResult() {
        Log.d("PICKERTEST", "onActivityResult")
        activityStopped()
    }
}
```

and call it in my Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    ...

    private fun pickFile() {
        ...

        val mainApplication = applicationContext as? MainApplication
        mainApplication?.onStartActivityForResult()
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val mainApplication = applicationContext as? MainApplication
        mainApplication?.onActivityResult()
    }
}
```

This is however a hack and also does not cover the case in which my Application is paused *while* showing the file picker.

Does anyone know a solution for listening to lifecycle events of external activities?

Comment: `In this case, I don't get callbacks for the picker activity` I have no idea what you mean by that. `and my app believes it gets paused, as soon as the picker appears. `. Yes that is quite normal. Your activity can be killed at any moment if it is not the top one.

Comment: Make your own picker as a dialog window so your activity is only partially covered and stays visible behind it.

Comment: @blackapps if you read well the beginning of my post, I have lifecycle callbacks implemented for the activities. Also, I said "my app" believes it gets paused, not my activity. Of course my main activity gets paused, but my application is still running. Also, I do not want to write custom code for something that works nicely and has the native feeling like the built-in file picker. Thanks anyways for your feedback!

Comment: "or if lifecycle callbacks just don't get called when I run an activity from a different package" -- it is a completely different process and a completely different app. Hence, you will not get lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: I would disagree that it's a different process (if you mean "process" as OS process). adb shows that the picker activity runs in the same process and on the same activity stack as the rest of my app: mRootProcess=ProcessRecord{8e6d1d0 18338:tech.mulloni.test.filepicker/u0a172}
    Running activities (most recent first):
      TaskRecord{ee729c3 #162 A=tech.mulloni.test.filepicker U=0 StackId=160 sz=2}
        Run #1: ActivityRecord{e05754 u0 com.android.documentsui/.picker.PickActivity t162}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{bb67e7d u0 tech.mulloni.test.filepicker/.MainActivity t162}

Comment: @AlessandroMulloni did you ever find a way around your problem?

Comment: @PhilipBulley unfortunately not a clean one. I add an explicit flag in my application that I set before going to an external activity (like the picker), combined with a large timeout (1 minute in my case).

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those asking or checking this question, here is my approach to the problem described in my question above. I understand it is not the cleanest solution possible but it solves the purpose.

```
class MainApplication: Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)
    }

    /// Activity counter

    private var startedActivities = AtomicInteger(0)
    private var waitingForExternalActivity = AtomicBoolean(false)

    private fun activityIsRunning(): Boolean {
        return (startedActivities.get() > 0)
    }

    /// Activity lifecycle callbacks

    override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {
        if (waitingForExternalActivity.getAndSet(false)) {
            cancelWaitingForExternalActivityTimeout()
            startedActivities.incrementAndGet()
        } else {
            if (startedActivities.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
                onApplicationStarted()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
        if (startedActivities.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            if (!waitingForExternalActivity.get() && !activity.isChangingConfigurations) {
                onApplicationStopped()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { }
    override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) { }
    override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) { }
    override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) { }
    override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) { }

    /// Custom callback

    fun onStartExternalActivity() {
        waitingForExternalActivity.set(true)
        scheduleWaitingForExternalActivityTimeout()
    }

    private val waitingForExternalActivityHandler = Handler()
    private val waitingForExternalActivityTimeout = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            waitingForExternalActivity.set(false)
            onApplicationStopped()
        }
    }

    private fun scheduleWaitingForExternalActivityTimeout() {
        waitingForExternalActivityHandler.postDelayed(waitingForExternalActivityTimeout, 60000)
    }

    private fun cancelWaitingForExternalActivityTimeout() {
        waitingForExternalActivityHandler.removeCallbacks(waitingForExternalActivityTimeout)
    }

    /// Application lifecycle - custom code

    private fun onApplicationStarted() {
        /// *** your code here
    }

    private fun onApplicationStopped() {
        /// *** your code here
    }
}
```

And in the rest of your code, wherever you start an external activity, you would need to first notify your application. For example:

```
fun pickFile(callback: ((Uri?) -> Unit)) {
    mainApplication.onStartExternalActivity()

    pickFileCallback = callback
    pickFileLauncher.launch(arrayOf("*/*"))
}
```